# Questions on the output of idealprimedec (PARI/GP)

Tags: pari-gp

I'm doing some computation with PARI/GP.
For some number field K, I need to deal with the splitting of a fixed prime ideal of K in its extension**s** say L1, L2,...

The problem is that when I want to use the command 'idealfactor,' I have to recover K by the command 'nfsubfields'. Then K is represented by a new minimal polynomial. I don't know a method to identify the initially fixed prime ideal to a prime ideal among the output of idealprimedec with respect to the new minimal polynomial.

I guess that the prime ideals obtained by idealprimedec are ordered with respect to some arithmetic information independent of the minimal polynomial choice.

I would like to know whether this is the case.

Thank you very much for reading this question.

I have already described what I have tried and what I'm expecting now.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal code example demonstrating your problem? You always can keep the polynomial, and reconstruct the field from it with help of `nfinit` command.

Comment: @PiotrSemenov  Hi. Thank you very much for your interest! First of all, my problem was solved by a suggestion of Allombert.  Still, I'm curious to know the answer to my question. Suppose that P and Q are two irreducible polynomials with rational coefficients. Suppose that P and Q represent the same number field. I want to know whether for each prime p, idealprimedec(bnfinit(P),p)[1] and idealprimedec(bnfinit(Q),p)[1] are the same prime ideal. In other words, I want to know whether the outputs of idealprimedec are ordered independently of the minimal polynomial. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 questions in one. First, how is the `idealprimedec` output sorted ? By increasing residue degree (P.f), then by some mathematically meaningless lexicographic ordering of P.gen[2]; in particular, it depends on the minimal polynomial used to define the number field. The exact same ordering is used in `idealfactor`, after ordering by increasing underlying rational prime. So, to detect whether a prime ideal given in terms of `nf1 = nfinit(T1)` is the same as another one given in terms of `nf2 = nfinit(T2)`, you cannot proceed directly besides comparing the underlying primes `P.gen[1]`, inertia degree `P.e` and residue degree `P.f`. If any of these differ, you have a definite answer; else you remain in doubt.

The second question is thus more interesting. How do you check whether `P1`
(given in terms of `nf1`) and `P2` (given in terms of `nf2`) are the same, knowing that the number fields `nf1` and `nf2` are isomorphic ? The way I recommend is as follows

- if `P2.f` is equal to the field degree, then the prime is inert and the    above preliminary test is enough.
- set `[p, pi] = P2.gen`: `p` is the underlying rational prime and `pi` is a `p`-uniformizer (its valuation is 1 at `P2` and 0 at all over primes dividing `p`), given in terms of the integer basis `nf2.zk`. N.B. this is not true when the prime is inert, you will have `pi = 0`.
- convert `pi` to polynomial representation using `pi = lift(nfbasistoalg(nf2, pi))`
- obtain one field isomorphism `s` relating `nf2` to `nf1` using `s = nfisincl(nf2, nf1, 1)` (the final '1' avoids computing *all* isomorphisms, we only need one).
- map `pi` from `nf2` to `nf1` using `PI = Mod(subst(pi, variable(pi), s), nf1.pol)`. You now have a representation of `pi` in `nf1`.

You can then check whether `idealval(nf1, PI, P1)` is positive (and in fact equal to 1), which will be the case if and only if `P1` and `P2`
are the same.

P.S. Independently, to study the decomposition of a fixed prime from `K` in multiple extensions `L1`, `L2`, etc., you may want to have a look at `rnfidealprimedec`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I will carefully study it.